# Supplier as a function

Tags: java

How does the following work? I pass a `Supplier` where a `Function` is expected.

```
class Scratch {
    private Bar bar = new Bar("foo");

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Scratch scratch = new Scratch();
        System.out.println(scratch.getBarValue(Bar::getValue));
    }

    public <T> T getBarValue(Function<Bar, T> extractor) {
        return extractor.apply(bar);
    }

    static class Bar {
        private String value;

        Bar(String value) {
            this.value = value;
        }

        String getValue() {
            return value;
        }
    }
}
```

I understand Java is creating a function from the supplier, but oddly can't find any documentation around this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`Bar::getValue` is a function that accepts a `Bar` instance and returns a string. It's not a supplier, because without a `Bar` instance, it cannot be called.

Given a specific instance, `bar::getValue` is a supplier, because it just gets the value from that particular instance of `Bar`. But `Bar::getValue` needs to be given an instance of `Bar` in order to call `getValue()` on it. So it's a `Function<Bar, String>`.

Answer (score 2):

`getValue()` appears to take no arguments but it actually has an implicit `this` parameter.

Normally that's disguised behind the syntactical sugar of `object.method(...)`. When you create a method reference with `::`, though, the implicit `this` becomes explicit. `getValue()` is then treated as a one-argument function since it can only be called if it knows what `Bar` it's being called on.

This happens with any instance method. It doesn't apply to `static` methods; they have no `this`.